# Query Custom Post Type Order By Taxonomy Field

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

This is driving me nuts. I know it's been asked a number of times but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to display a list of WooCommerce products--which are a custom post type of 'product'. I want to sort it by a taxonomy of 'product_cat'.

In the following code, the inner while loop (query) -should- display only the products for each product_cat, but instead, it displays -all- products.

Why isn't the query filtering each product_cat?

```
// loop through the categories
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
  $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
        $cat_slug = $cat->slug;
  // Make a header for the category
  echo "<h2>".$cat->slug.' '. $cat_id . "</h2>";
  // create a custom wordpress query

      $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'terms'    => $cat_id,
                'field'    => 'term_id',                    
            ),
        );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
            $p = get_the_ID();
                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            /* Restore original Post Data */
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            // no posts found
                echo('no posts!');  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `tax_query` key, and it needs to be a nested array:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms' => $cat_id,
            'field' => 'term_id',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Check [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)